# Why is "new String[] { }" used while updating or deleting an item in SQLite database in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

**new String[] { }** is used while updating and deleting an item from **SQLite** database, such as:

At first, creating the table:

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT)");
```

Updating an item:

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?",new String[] {id});
```

Deleting an item:

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?",new String[] {id});
```

Here, `ID` was an **INTEGER** while creating the table in database. But, while updating/deleting any item, `id` was already a **String**, then why should we use **new String[] {id}**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question.

***Why new String[] {id} ?***

Here **new String[] {id}** is the initalization of a String array, an array is needed because the number of parameters can be one or many.

***Why is this array of String type ?***

The parameters we pass to query can be anything among **integer/float/string**, It is trivial/easy/human-readable to convert **integer/float** to **String** but not vice-versa. In Java, code has to be fixed (Unlike Python), thus the creators have to stick with **String**, I guess.

***Bonus:***

This way of SQL query generation (Instead of writing query directly) which is called prepared-statements/Parameterized-Queries and it is a good way to combat SQL-Injection.

Comment: Would you please briefly explain **the number of parameters can be one or many** and I will accept your answer.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]) The answer lies within the whereClause parameter. You can have a whereClause having multiple parameters like this "ID = ? AND name = ?", here you need to pass two values to the clause thus you need to have a String array carrying both the values.

Comment: cont... It is easy for the API developer(here sqlite API developers) to have one function which works for both one parameter clause("id = ?") and multiple parameter clause("id = ? AND name = ?") by using String Array, instead of having two seperate functions for both the scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

As it is explained in [4.2. Type Conversions Prior To Comparison](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_conversions_prior_to_comparison), prior to this comparison `ID = ?`, for the parameter that you pass, although it is a string, `NUMERIC` affinity is applied because the column `ID` has `INTEGER` affinity.

So the norm is: you always pass a string parameter but when the sql statement is executed, this string parameter will be implicitly converted/treated as either a string if it is compared to a string (a column with `TEXT` affinity), or a number if it is compared to a number (a column with `INTEGER` or `NUMERIC` affinity).

Answer (score 1):

The argument you have mentioned **new String[] {id}** is used for WHERE clause arguments.It is helpful when you use WHERE clause. And that stuff is helpful to provide arguments.
For further clarification you may visit below link:

[Where clause argument while using delete query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D))